# DigitalOcean DNS or my computer returning ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED for my website domain

Tags: domain-name-system, osx-yosemite

Two people (me - the webmaster - and a regular user, for now) that accessed our site `www.lastroarte.com`  are having `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` error on Chrome and any other browsers are just not finding the page and they do not display error logs upfront, so I'm assuming its the same error. (I haven't searched for it as well)

When I type the IP-address it works fine. So I believe it's a DNS error. Here is the `whois` on my domain:

```
Name Server: NS1.DIGITALOCEAN.COM
Name Server: NS2.DIGITALOCEAN.COM
Name Server: NS3.DIGITALOCEAN.COM
DNSSEC: unSigned
```

Looks good right? Maybe this DNSSEC?

I've seen some tips around the Internet,

- Flush DNS
- Clear Chrome DNS Cache
- Reboot server
- Checked /etc/private/hosts file for misleadign entries
- Turned firewall off
- Checked whois
- Checked google's public DNS
- Used googles and OpenDNS DNS ips on my network settings
- etc

but none works. I still believe its my computer.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

I'm on a `MacBook Pro` Running `Yosemite 10.10` on WiFi under a router.

Answer (score 8):

> Two people (me - the webmaster - and a regular user, for now) that accessed our site www.lastroarte.com are having ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error on Chrome and any other browsers are just not finding the page and they do not display error logs upfront, so I'm assuming its the same error. (I haven't searched for it as well)

Don't rely on browser DNS cache when troubleshooting DNS problems. Depending on the host OS, use `dig` or `nslookup`. On the affected computers, which appear to be running OS X, run `dig +trace www.lastroarte.com` and then `dig a www.lastroarte.com` and paste the output.

What it appears is that there is no A or CNAME record for www, but there is an A record for lastroarte.com. Once you CNAME www to lastroarte.com you'll be fine.

Comment: curl-D and dig +trace return this: [https://cloudup.com/i3G5HdQ3yA3][1]

Comment: @user3842869 Yeah, you don't have any record in DNS for www, so nothing will return for anyway. I'm not getting your website when I go to www.lastroarte.com, but do when I go to lastroarte.com.

Comment: heres is my Records Page on Digital Ocean, should I add a CNAME record now? What should I put as name and hostname? Thanks mate! https://cloudup.com/cQn9bxbMeBU

Comment: @user3842869 So you need to add a CNAME. In the "Enter Name" section put `www` and in the hostname section put `lastroarte.com.`

Comment: still dint works, I'll add the registers on my old server setup to see if its any CNMAE A or NS register that is misisng.

Comment: @user3842869 Yes, it worked as per my test of dig and going to www.lastroarte.com. just now. You didn't wait long enough for DNS to change on your local PC and probably have cached responses.

Comment: YEAH! You were absolutely right Wesley, faster then the official support from DigitalOcean, although they are also very efficient.Thank you so much. All woks great perfectly now!

Comment: @user3842869 Glad to help! Don't forget to accept the answer for the benefit of future readers. =)